# Samsung Smart TV - Accessing microphone data

Tags: api, microphone, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to create a Samsung Smart TV app that should take audio data from the (built-in or connected) microphone and send it to a server on the internet for evaluation.

My question is about the microphone. I've looked through the [Microphone API](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00008/dtv_microphone_microphone.html#play), but there are no methods with which I can access the raw audio data, only to put the stream directly to the speakers.
Apparently, it is also not possible to access the microphone through Flash at all.

It has to be possible somehow, because Skype is available for Samsung Smart TV. Though, Skype might be a native app.

Does anyone know of a way of accessing the audio stream that works around the limitations of the Samsung API? If not, how would it be possible to write a native app? Am I right in the assumption that this would require negotiations with Samsung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do would have privacy considerations.

Because of this I would think that the Skype app has special dispensation to write an approved app to use the microphone data - and send it to Skype servers.